# KVM including network?

Tags: networking, ethernet, kvm-switch

I have a situation where there are two computers and only one display, keyboard and mouse to control them. The obvious solution would be to use a KVM to switch between PC one and two to control them.

However, there is only one ethernet connection available at this particular location. Ideally I would like to have a KVM which includes network, so when I use PC one, PC one would be connected, and when I use PC two, PC two would become connected.

I've never heard of such a device - does anybody know if such a device exists? And if so, could you recommend me one?

PS: I'm asking this because this is a setup for a new office in which there are too few ethernet connections, no WiFi, and absolutely no possibility to add ethernet cables. Switches and routers are not allowed to be used, so those are out of the question as well.

Comment: “Switches and routers are not allowed to be used” – but plugging in different devices is allowed? IMHO quite nonsensical.

Comment: @DanielB - both computers are known and whitelisted on the domain, switches and routers are not allowed because they cannot be managed via the same center our edge switches are managed. Buying an edge switch for 2 connections is of course not an option. This is just a situation in a new building where 2 connections were asked, yet only one connection was placed. Since adding a cable is not an option, we're now looking for another solution. As for plugging in different devices, of course everybody is free to plug in any whitelisted device in any connection (that's why they are whitelisted).

Comment: I never heard of such a device you're asking about. That's usually accomplished by using switches. Even if you move KVM from one computer to another, there usually are reasons to still keep the network connection up, so this wouldn't be useful anyway.
If the end devices need to be whitelisted to work, plugging in an unmanaged switch does not pose any security threat. The devices connected to that switch need to be whitelisted anyway. So if there is only one ethernet socket in the room, why the pwople who manage the network don't just put a simple unmanaged switch there?

Comment: If they are absolutely against switches and cannot be convinced to plug in one, ask them to use an Ethernet splitter. This must be on both sides: on the side of edge switch, the cable going to your room needs to be connected to splitter and **both** cables from splitter need to be connected to separate ports on edge switch; in the room, plug the splitter into ethernet socket and connect both computers to both connections coming out of the splitter. With this method both computers are independently connected to edge switch.

Comment: @raj - if you plug in an unmanaged switch on a managed switch and it detects one whitelisted MAC address on the unmanaged switch, the managed switch will allow all connections via that unmanaged switch. This is actually a very well known attack vector, hence why unmanaged switches are not allowed. 
Thanks for the suggestion of a splitter, but this would limit the speed to 100MBit, which is not acceptable.
Having no network for one PC is no problem, it is always one or the other that need network.

Comment: There are KVM devices that include an USB port. Maybe if you use such device, and behind it plug a USB-to-Ethernet adapter, you may accomplish what you need (but this adapter needs to be whitelisted itself, which gives the option to connect any computer to it - so they may not allow it as well).

Comment: Also, there are managed switches that filter MAC addresses throughout the entire switch and not based on particular port. I'm used to this kind of switches. In these switches the attack you described is not possible because each MAC address is treated individually.

Comment: @raj MAC addresses are easy to clone.

Comment: @eventHandler If we assume someone will be cloning MACs, then the "whitelisting" of devices based on MAC address OP is talking about has little sense at all, right?

Comment: If this is for work, then push back... unless you work in IT, it's probably not your job to come up with IT solutions to their restrictive world views... their job is to facilitate you. If that means facilitating the use of two legitimate systems, then they need to cooperate. MAC whitelisting is not a strong security model.

Comment: @Attie - I am from the IT department. We asked for more connections in the building, but didn't get them. So now we're stuck with this kind of situations. Adding a cable is not an option, any solution which has only one computer is not an option. The only solution we can see so far, is one where we can switch the use of both computers with a button (because the user needs to have an easy solution), hence the question for a KVM like device.
Cloning the MAC address isn't the issue, if an edge switch allows one MAC on an unmanaged switch, it allows all other ports as well.

Comment: "_I am from the IT department_" - apologies :-) ... A USB Ethernet dongle paired with a USB KVM is likely your best bet here... but it's not going to give a great experience for obvious reasons (performance, disconnections, etc...)

Comment: @Attie - thanks for the information,and yes I agree, it's not the ideal solution. But then again we asked for more cables when they started building and never got them... so an ideal solution was never an option I'm afraid.

Comment: ... if you have spare ports at the local switch, and are willing to run at 100Mbit/s, then you can try an "_[Ethernet Splitter](https://www.distrelec.biz/Web/WebShopImages/landscape_large/1-/01/Valueline-21_99_3050-30113441-01.jpg)_"... horrible / misleading name, and you need to be careful about what you're actually buying, but permits 2x 100Mbit/s connections over one fully-wired / 4-pair RJ-45 (_not_ Gigabit, and _will not_ work over 2-pair wiring) - you'll need one at each end.